# ¿Mostrar valores especificos en un formulario de Symfony?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, symfony2, doctrine2, doctrine

Estoy creando un formulario en Symfony en el que se deben elegir una categoría y una subcategoria que depende de la categoría principal (por ejemplo, si se selecciona Música las subcategorias son pop, rock, etc... y si es Espectáculos deben ser infantil, adultos, etc...

Las categorias están relacionadas en la base de datos sin problemas. La tabla Subcategorias contiene un campo en el que se almacena la categoria padre del elemento.

He creado el formulario pero en el desplegable con las subcategorias aparecen todas, cuando solo deberian mostrarse las que pertenezcan a la categoria padre que esté seleccionada.

¿Como lo soluciono?

Este es el constructor del formulario

```
//EnquiryType.php
class EnquiryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('categoria');
        $builder->add('subcategoria');
        $builder->add('espectadores');
        $builder->add('fecha');
        $builder->add('hora');
        $builder->add('tiempo');
        $builder->add('presupuesto');
        $builder->add('material', 'radio');
        $builder->add('materiales');
        $builder->add('informacion');    
    }
```

Y este es el controller

```
 //EventController.php
class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {     

        $evento = new Evento();
        $form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $evento);


        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('CASEventBundle_create'));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('CASEventBundle:Default:form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Espero no sea muy tarde, debes seguramente trabajar con eventos de formulario, o hacer el formulario sin usar el componente form

```
<form>
   <select onchange="llamoMiServicioDepende()">
      <option value="1">Value1</option>
   </select>
   <select id="hijo"> /*Recargas por js los valores de este select al cambiar el select de arriba*/
      <option value="1">Value1</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Si ves q solo lo necesitas una vez, podría ser una solución válida (tienes q manejar la seguridad de tu formulario manualmente :(  )
O podrìas usar las soluciones de estas web, que son mas geniales:
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://vabadus.es/blog/select-dependientes-y-autocompletados-en-symfony2)
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-selects-dependientes-mediante-eventos/)

Comment: Ya lo solucioné de otra manera hace tiempo, pero gracias por contestar :)

Comment: Puedes colocar como lo solucionaste?